# How to access php object index only

Tags: php, arrays, object

Am having a little issue accessing the index of an array, any help

```php
{
    "37": {},
    "38": {}
}
```

Comment: What you have shown looks more like a json string than an array

Comment: How are you *accessing the index*? Can you show the code which you have.

Answer (score 1):

PHP `array_keys()` will give you the keys only.

See, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php